# Sorting by _id results in column scan

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

I have a price collection with product ids in it, I have indexed the productid so that getting prices from productid is fast. Had a need to do some aggregation, so added a match phase with productid and then added in sort phase with _id so that I can sort the results in descending order, thought documents will be first filtered based on match phase and then sorted based on _id. But when I run explain, I can see that keypattern used is `{"_id" : 1}` and the index on productid is not used. From keysExamined, I can see that the entire collection is scanned as keysExamined equals the size of collection. If I remove the sort phase, everything runs as expected, index on productid is used and keysExamined is much lesser like how its supposed to be. Am I missing something here with sort based on _id? Any help on this is much appreciated.

```
db.prices
  .explain("executionStats")
  .aggregate([
    { $match: { product: ObjectId("5fc1c4ed65fb2cbf839a0324") } },
    { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
]);




{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.prices",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "product" : {
                "$eq" : ObjectId("5fc1c4ed65fb2cbf839a0324")
            }
        },
        "optimizedPipeline" : true,
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "product" : {
                    "$eq" : ObjectId("5fc1c4ed65fb2cbf839a0324")
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "_id_",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "_id" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : true,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "backward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "_id" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 2,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 2,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 2,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 2,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "product" : {
                    "$eq" : ObjectId("5fc1c4ed65fb2cbf839a0324")
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 2,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 3,
            "advanced" : 2,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "docsExamined" : 2,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 2,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 3,
                "advanced" : 2,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "_id_",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "_id" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : true,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "backward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "_id" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 2,
                "seeks" : 1,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Please note that above is just an example I created in local setup where this issue can be seen.

Comment: Can you share all indexes for this collection? Seems you have `productid` and `product` fields

Comment: Sure, the collection has the following schema `{product: ObjectId, price: Number, size: String}` and I just have an index on `product` apart from `_id`

Comment: Your query plan shows 2 documents examined. Add sample data to the question and use that sample data when you are explaining.

Comment: And # examined = # returned which is the best that can be done.